# Error converting data type nvarchar to bit in asp

Tags: exception, asp-classic, commandparameter

I have an asp application.

I am using the following code:

```
Comm.Parameters.Append Comm.CreateParameter("@IsSecure", adBoolean, adParamInput, , True)
```

I have used parameter and the datatype is set to `Boolean`.
But whenever I execute it, I get an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bit

Am I doing anything wrong?

Can anyone please help me out of this.

Comment: Have you tried using `1` or `0` instead of `True` and `False`?

Comment: yes with that also the same error.
I had also tried using integer datatype instead of boolean, same failure!!!

Comment: _If you are using ADO 2.7 or higher, set the .NamedParameters property to True._. [Source](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=405384)